# I live on the border between central and eastern time, and want a solution to keep the phone from changing without manually doing it each time

Tags: iphone

I recently purchased an new iPhone 6 and now the time zone keep changing.  I live in a border town which is on eastern time but the Phoenix changes to central time.  My old iPhone 6 did not do this, how can I keep this from happening without changing the settings, as I do frequently travel to other time zones and do not want to change my phone on each trip?

Comment: As far as I know this is dictated by your phone carrier. It's possible the new phone is accessing different cell sites and thus causing the flip flopping. Or did you change carriers during the upgrade to the new iPhone?